# JAVA SWING: Vector used in Default Table Model fails to addElement() added through a for loop

Tags: java, swing, vector, jtable, defaulttablemodel

Two Jtables in this example show a challenge am facing. Simply put,one table is a Master table while the second depends on the Master table data. Master table contains data which on column 3 is Boolean, the purpose of the second table is simply to display all data that on column 3 which is true(Names of all Males). In other words, all data that is false as far as column 3 on Master table is concerned is not to be displayed.
The problem is that when I ran the code, only **one** element is displayed in the second table while other data which is 'Boolean=true' is ignored as shown below.
[image]

What might be wrong with my code which fails to display all Boolean true data on the second table.NOTE: I also tried to used the DefaultTableModel addRow() method within the loop but also failed to display all data that is true from MasterTable Column 3.

```
public class ZoomTable extends JFrame{

    JPanel panel;
    Object [] masterColumns = new Object []{"Name","Age","Male"};
    Object [][] masterData = new Object [][]{
       {"Simon",10,new Boolean(true)},
       {"Jane",10,new Boolean(false)},
       {"Hellen",10,new Boolean(false)},
       {"Amos",10,new Boolean(true)},
       {"Brenda",10,new Boolean(false)},
       {"Dennis",10,new Boolean(true)},
       {"Mary",10,new Boolean(false)},
       };
    MasterTableModel mtm = new MasterTableModel(masterData,masterColumns);
    Vector<Vector> maleListData = new Vector<Vector>();
    Vector maleList = new Vector();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ZoomTable zoom = new ZoomTable();
       zoom.init();
       zoom.setVisible(true);
       zoom.setSize(new Dimension(600,800));
       zoom.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    void init(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable masterTable = new JTable(masterData,masterColumns);
        JScrollPane spMaster = new JScrollPane();
        spMaster.setViewportView(masterTable);
        panel.add(spMaster,"North");

        Vector <String> tinyColumns = new Vector <String>();       
        tinyColumns.addElement("NAMES OF MALES");

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new           DefaultTableModel(maleListVector(),tinyColumns);
        JTable tinyTable = new JTable(dtm); 
        JScrollPane spTiny = new JScrollPane();
        spTiny.setViewportView(tinyTable);
        panel.add(spTiny,"Center");
        add(panel);
        pack();
    }

    public Vector maleListVector(){
        for(int k = 0;k < mtm.getRowCount();k++){

            if(mtm.getValueAt(k,2).equals(true)){
                String maleName = mtm.getValueAt(k,0).toString();
                maleList.addElement(maleName);
            System.out.println(maleName+" is Male");
            }
            else if(mtm.getValueAt(k,2).equals(false)){
                String femaleName = mtm.getValueAt(k,0).toString();
              System.out.println(femaleName+" is Female");
            }


         }
        maleListData.add(maleList);
     return maleListData;}
}

class MasterTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    Object [][] data;
    Object [] cols;

    MasterTableModel(Object[][] masterData, Object[] masterColumns) {
       data = masterData;
       cols = masterColumns;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
       return cols.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
       return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for the DefaultTableModel is a Vector of Vectors.

You only ever add one Vector to the "maleListData" so this means you have a single row with multiple columns of data.

This is easy to verify. Just change your code to:

```
tinyColumns.addElement("NAMES OF MALES");
tinyColumns.addElement("2");
```

and you will see another column of data.

So the solution to your problem is to add a new row of data to the Vector for every male item you find:

```
//maleList.addElement(maleName);
Vector row = new Vector(1);
row.add(maleName);
maleListData.addElement( row );

...

//maleListData.add(maleList);
```

Comment: hahahahahaha!!!! what a subtle but stupid mistake i made.Thanks a million @camickr. you always come thru.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in other answers, the specific problem here is you were only ever adding the first element of the vector to your `maleListData`. To fix this you could either create a vector with one element in, like camickr did, and add this to your `maleListData` in each iteration of your for loop. Or you could use the `addAll` method with a little modification of your code.

---

Some suggestions. Make your code a little more OOP. The use of generics and keywords to do with scope, like `private`, can make your code more readable and easier to understand. It also prevents it being used in the wrong way.

In this case by `use of generics` I mean specifying to types of your vectors so that IDEs like Eclipse don't throw a load of warnings at you.

For example, with your fixed class.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ZoomTable extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panel;
    private Object[] masterColumns = new Object[]{"Name","Age","Male"};
    private Object[][] masterData = new Object[][]{
        {"Simon", 10, true},
        {"Jane", 10, false},
        {"Hellen", 10, false},
        {"Amos",10, true},
        {"Brenda",10, false},
        {"Dennis",10, true},
        {"Mary",10, false},
    };
    private MasterTableModel mtm = new MasterTableModel(masterData,masterColumns);
    private Vector<Vector<Object>> maleListData = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoomTable zoom = new ZoomTable();
        zoom.init();
        zoom.setVisible(true);
        zoom.setSize(new Dimension(600,800));
        zoom.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void init(){
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTable masterTable = new JTable(masterData,masterColumns);
        JScrollPane spMaster = new JScrollPane();
        spMaster.setViewportView(masterTable);
        panel.add(spMaster,"North");

        Vector <String> tinyColumns = new Vector <String>();       
        tinyColumns.addElement("NAMES OF MALES");

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(maleListVector(), tinyColumns);
        JTable tinyTable = new JTable(dtm); 
        JScrollPane spTiny = new JScrollPane();
        spTiny.setViewportView(tinyTable);
        panel.add(spTiny,"Center");
        add(panel);
        pack();
    }

    private Vector<Vector<Object>> maleListVector(){
        for(int k = 0;k < mtm.getRowCount();k++){
            if(mtm.getValueAt(k, 2).equals(true)){
                String maleName = mtm.getValueAt(k, 0).toString();
                Vector<Object> name = new Vector<Object>();
                name.add(maleName);
                maleListData.addElement(name);
                System.out.println(maleName + " is Male");
            } else if(mtm.getValueAt(k, 2).equals(false)){
                String femaleName = mtm.getValueAt(k, 0).toString();
                System.out.println(femaleName + " is Female");
            }
        }
        return maleListData;
    }

    private class MasterTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
        Object[][] data;
        Object[] cols;

        MasterTableModel(Object[][] masterData, Object[] masterColumns) {
            data = masterData;
            cols = masterColumns;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return cols.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Afroid1000 No worries. Glad I could help